# How do I add a foreign key in the newly updated phpmyadmin?

Tags: mysql, indexing, foreign-keys

I have a table called Users with a primary key of id and I would like to add a foreign key in my other table called Students with a foreign key of user_id pointing to the id in the Users table. Here is the sql I am trying to use:

```
ALTER TABLE Students ADD COLUMN user_id INTEGER NULL, ADD CONSTRAINT FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES Users(id);
```

It is not registering as a foreign key, so my question is how do go about setting up a foreign key in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was using the wrong type of table, I had to recreate the tables using the InnoDb type in order to add foreign keys!

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  You should accept your own answer, so that this question will be marked accurately as answered.

Comment: StackOverflow is making me wait 2 days to do that :/

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE Students
ADD FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
REFERENCES users(id)
```

Should work.  Add the column first, then try this as a separate statement.  Also, are you sure you want user_id to be NULL by default?